# Can't communicate with SMTP server from particular machine

Tags: linux, smtp, email-server, linux-networking, exim

Here is the situation:

[image]

When I run the following on my local machine, the mail server responds:

```
$ telnet mail.server.com 2525
Trying <mail.server.com IP>...
Connected to mail.server.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220-<provider-server-name> ESMTP Exim 4.82 #2 Sun, 05 Apr 2015 11:49:13 -0500 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
220 and/or bulk e-mail.
```

And it responds to my commands.

When I run the same command from the bad server, I get:

```
$ telnet mail.server.com 2525
Trying <mail.server.com IP>...
Connected to mail.server.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

This text is missing:

```
220-<provider-server-name.com> ESMTP Exim 4.82 #2 Sun, 05 Apr 2015 11:49:13 -0500 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
220 and/or bulk e-mail.
```

And it doesn't respond to my commands.
I cleaned all iptables rules, accepting everything on bad server. Then I tried to setup a blocking rule on port 2525 to check, that maybe something is wrong with iptables.

```
# /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2525 -j DROP
# telnet mail.server.com 2525
Trying <mail.server.com IP>...
```

It can't connect. So, it's not iptables.

SELinux is off:

```
# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

I have no idea, what could be blocking SMTP traffic. It connects to server, but I get no response from it. Admins on SMTP server checked and said, that bad server is not inside it's blacklist.

Comment: If the server answers, it is definitely **not** `iptables`. Check your Exim configuration whether the server is allowed to use the SMTP. For relay, you should of course have some kind of authentication, too.

Comment: Have you access to the mail server log? That might contain more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Long waiting for SMTP greeting

How long do you wait to get SMTP greeting message?
Exact duration in seconds may provide very important hint.

AFAIR some servers issue SMTP greeting message **after** doing DNS lookups (IP address -> DNS name -> IP address).  Typical timeout for single DNS query is 75s.  DNS is not the only suspect (e.g. ident timeout may be 30s).

Comment: I didn't wait for long. Cause on my machine I got instant response. How can I check the incorrect DNS lookup on the mail server?

Comment: Check if you get the SMTP greeting after (long) delay. Exact duration of the delay may provide very important hint.  DNS is not the only suspect.

Comment: Yes, I get the response in 2 minutes 20 seconds. How to check, what's wrong with DNS?

Comment: I have seen this behaviour if this machine is not in DNS and the nameserver list includes IP-numbers not able to respond so timeouts have to occur.

Comment: Maybe you listed multiple DNS servers in your `/etc/resolv.conf` and some of them are unreachable/faulty.

Comment: DNS checks for PTR-A loop: 1) PTR record (IP address->DNS name) `nslookup ip_address` 2) A record (DNS name -> IP address) `nslookup dns_name`

Comment: @ManuelFaux AFAIR DNS resolver tries next DNS server after 5s wait. It makes 140s delay unlikely for "some DNS servers are unreachable" with typical 2-3 DNS servers configured.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look in /etc/hosts.deny ?

Comment: It can't be host, cause the connection to SMTP server is established. But I get no data from it.

Comment: No, actually, that's the "normal" behaviour when something is blocked by TCP wrappers. It will allow the initial connection, but after that it drops. Try it with something like ssh and you'll see that exact behaviour.

Comment: hosts.deny on the mail server or bad server?

Comment: On the mail server. Might as well check /etc/hosts.allow at the same time.

Comment: Although with TCP wrappers, it does drop/close the connection, so that may not be it... it could be doing a DNS reverse lookup as the previous commenter suggested. Try waiting for 60 seconds or more

Comment: Ahh, yes, after waiting for 4 minutes I got the response on bad server. So, it's the reverse DNS. How can I fix it?

Comment: The "short cut" is to add the IP of your "bad server" in /etc/hosts on the mail server. But you might want to look into it a little deeper. If the mail server is unable to do DNS lookups, every host will get this delay. If it's just an issue with your "bad server" not having a DNS reverse mapping, I dont see why that would cause such a delay.